# Is there a way to save pop up alerts?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, logging

After every call/message, my service provider (airtel) displays a popup which has the last call cost and current balance. Is there a way I could log them automatically and have the latest balance displayed as a widget in home screen? Is it possible to capture that using code? I am using a Galaxy S phone.

Comment: What a bad provider/carrier behavior, I would complain about it. :-(

Comment: It's not bad, it's done for prepaid connections. Otherwise how would you know how much balance you have?

Comment: If you want to develop or developing then this question should move to Stack overflow. All devel queries are answered there.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to take a screenshot after the fact. This works natively on ICS by pressing volume down and power key together, otherwise root the phone and install a screen capture app.